# Simple problem about a pyramid

Tags: geometry

$ABCDM$ is a pyramid such that the base $ABCD$ is a square and $MD\perp AD,MD\perp CD$ . If $P$ is the midpoint of $BD$, find the angle between $MP$ and $AC$.

Since $ABCD$ is a square and $P$ is the midpoint of the diagonal $BD$, then $AC$ is also bisected by $P$ (or $P$ is the intersection of the diagonals of the square). We have $MD\perp AD;MD\perp CD \Rightarrow MD\perp(ABCD)$ (it's perpendicular to intersecting lines lying in the same plane).

I don't know what I am supposed to do next. We can say $MD\perp BD$, but does it help?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Hints:**

1. Show $MA=MC$
2. $\triangle MAC$ is isosceles, so the median $MP$ ...

Comment: Thank you for the response! Any hints on showing $MA=MC$?

Comment: What do you know about triangles $MAD$ and $MCD$?

Comment: They are congruent, thank you!